# Unable to interact with modal using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, modal-dialog, phantomjs

I am stuck here for too long. A web application throws open a modal after the successful sign-in. After you select a particular option in the modal, you are able to proceed further with the web application. I am able to enter username and password, click the button but unable to detect the modal. I have also tried waiting indefinitely but no help.

Here is the code that I am using to sign-in into the website.

```
 page.open('https://example.com/login/auth', function (status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            $('[name="email"]').val('username');
            $('[name="password"]').val('password');
            $('.btn-login').click();
        });


        do {
            phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove');
            console.log('^^')
        } while (page.loading)

        setInterval(function () {
            page.evaluate(function () { console.log($('.modal-header').text(), " .... ") });
            page.render('after-login.png')
        },5000)
});

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function () {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
};
```

The statement `$(.modal-header).text()` always returns empty. Is it not possible to interact with modal using phantomJS?

Comment: You have partial answer in your description: "A web application throws open a modal after the successful sign-in". Try to $(.modal-header).text() wrap up in setTimeout function (let's say 10 sec) and see what happened. Ideally you'll need to interact with your modal when it'll be successful of failure login.

Comment: @Observer I tried checking after each 5 seconds, but got nothing.

Comment: @Observer Don't know, if I am making any mistake. The screenshot shows that the username and password have been entered.

Comment: What is `page.loading`? There is no built-in property like that in `page` object: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/

Comment: You're trying to interact with a modal on the first page load, when there isn't one. `I tried checking after each 5 seconds` Please show how you did that.

Comment: @Vaviloff Updated my code

Comment: @Vaviloff Is it correct?

Comment: The `setInterval` part looks great and now try to remove `do{} while()` block cause it's incorrect (at least in this sample it is)

Comment: Removed, `$('.modal-header').text()`  is always empty.

Comment: @Vaviloff Are you sure phantomjs can handle modals? I am apprehensive.

Comment: By modal you probably mean some `div` in `HTML` that is positioned above all other content. If it's just HTML, of course PhantomJS can handle that, I've done way more complicated stuff. The trick is to come up with correct code for `page.evaluate`. In `after-login.png` do you see a modal?

Comment: Just noticed one thing: have you implemented `page.onConsoleMessage` in your script? http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html If not, `console.log` from inside of `page.evaluate` just won't reach your console!

Comment: @Vaviloff no, cannot see the modal. I have implemented `page.onConsoleMessage`. Updated the code in question

Comment: `cannot see the modal` Oh, well, maybe something went wrong, you should subscribe to `page.onError` callback and check if scripts on the target page are even working.

Comment: @Vaviloff No error! I don't even think the button is getting clicked. If I enter the incorrect credentials, I see no error message from the screenshot captured

Comment: @Vaviloff If I try to click the button the same way on the chrome's console, it works fine and works fine if I enter the incorrect password too. Do you think there could be an issue, that phantomjs is not able to deal/detect with some javascript?